# What is the correct way to run a script from the "project root"?

Tags: c, linux, unix

https://github.com/nlsandler/nqcc

I recently came across this C compiler, and even though the instructions are right there, I can't seem to be able to produce an executable.

Here is a program called return_2.c located in ~

```c
int main(){
    return 2;
}
```

I ran `git clone URL` in `~`, and ran `make` in `~/nqcc` if that makes a difference..

From `~`, I run this: `./nqcc/nqcc return_2.c`

The exit code is `0` and there are no errors, so I don't know why I don't get a corresponding executable.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: generally by tradition a compiler will name the output a.out if you dont specify and output file name..

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yes, this is true, but in the readme.md that the author provided on their github page, just doing the command I did should give a corresponding executable

Comment: Did you check ./nqcc?  You may want to execute `strace` to see what the binary is doing.  If neither of those work, you might want to try contacting the project owner.

Comment: @Jason What exact command do you want me to run with strace? I'm not familiar with this utility

Comment: @herophant You can use `strace` to see what the `nqcc` binary actually does (e.g. `strace ./nqcc/nqcc return_2.c`).

Comment: Edit the `nqcc` script and remove `2>/dev/null` from the second to last line, then rerun the command. Do you get errors?

Comment: @Jason It's not even a binary, it's a shell script.

Comment: @melpomene Adding `-x` to the shebang might be an easier way to see what the script is doing.

Comment: I can just read what the script is doing: `gcc-8 -m32 $assembly -o $out -fno-pie 2>/dev/null`. It's running `gcc-8` and throwing away all error messages (such as `gcc-8` not existing on the system in question).

Answer (score 0):

As the instructions seem to tell us, most probably you need to change into the directory of the nqcc project and run the compiler there:

```
$ cd ~/nqcc
$ ./nqcc ../return_2.c
```

Looks like the scripts expect to be run on site.